# Despite Multiarch settings, Ubuntu 16.04 fails to keeping both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries installed in OS

Tags: apt, 16.04, package-management, multiarch, cross-compilation

I need to compile/link 32 bit and 64 bit C/C++ executables on Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit).  I executed the following commandlines:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install automake libtool libtool-bin
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib 
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

The last command will install 64 bit glib2.0 library

But when I try to install the 32 bit glib2.0 library via command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev:i386
```

It uninstalls the 64 bit glib2.0 library I just installed earlier (as noted by the remove comment after issuing the 32 bit install):

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev:i386
[sudo] password for dev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libltdl-dev:i386 libltdl7:i386 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libxext-dev:i386 libxext6:i386
libxfixes-dev:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libglib2.0-doc:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libglib2.0-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,422 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,367 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Could someone tell me how can I prevent the removal of 64 bit glib2.0 libraries (as well as other libraries I may install) when installing its 32 bit version on Ubuntu 16.04.  I need both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries installed for my C/C++ build.

As noted by the list of commands I executed, I did add 32 bit architecture to my 64 bit Ubuntu and verified that it is being recognized by the OS:

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
dev@ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

So based on the above query, there should be no reason why I can't have a glib2.0 library that is 64 bit and 32 bit (or for any library that has both 64/32 bit libraries available) installed in the same 64-bit OS, right?  At least this is what the [debian multiarch link tells me](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Availability).

If so, where am I going wrong here, that the package manager is disallowing this?  Multiarch, is support on Ubuntu 16.04, right?